# Loop through file with similar names

Tags: perl, loops, file-io, dir

How can I loop through files with similar names? This script works just for the first line of the first file and I don't understand the reason. Is there a simpler way to do it? 
This script has been created in order to read files, and write in another file all lines without numbers inside.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;
#read OUT_AM3.txt, OUT_MOV3.txt, OUT_TA3.txt

opendir (DIR, '.') or die "Couldn't open directory, $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;

$out = "Res.txt";
open (O, ">>", $out);
binmode(O, "utf8");

@eti = ("AM3","TA3","MOV3");
for ($i = 0; $i < @eti; $i++){
      foreach $fh(@files){
            open($fh, "<", "OUT_$eti[$i].txt");
            binmode($fh, "utf8");

            while(defined($l = <$fh>)){
                if (!grep /\-?\d\.\d+/, $l){
                print O $l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If script doesn't what you want, you have to better explain what is desired outcome.

Comment: edited just now.. But it's not very important the result. I would like know how to open each file in the directory without writing always the name of the file.  So I know that my files are always "OUT_xxx.txt", where "xxx" is the only difference through all these files. So I have : OUT_AM3, OUT_MOV3, OUT_TA3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"But it's not very important the result. I would like know how to open each file in the directory without writing always the name of the file. "

If I understand you correctly, you might want this?

```
my @files = grep /OUT_.*/, glob("*");
print $_ . "\n" foreach @files;
```

Or if you don't mind using module. There is File::Find::Rule

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my $rule =  File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->file;
$rule->name( 'OUT_*' );
my @files = $rule->in( "." );
```

Both will give a list of file name in @files.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need

```
for ($i = 0; $i < @eti; $i++)
```

as it will loop three times over all files found in directory.

Also, when looping over `@files` it is expected to use array elements,

```
  foreach my $file (@files) {
     -f $file or next;

     open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die $!;
     # ..
  }
```